# How many times is function called

Tags: sql-server

Lets have a following query:

```
SELECT * FROM {tablename} WHERE ColumnId = dbo.GetId()
```

where dbo.GetId() is non-deterministic user defined function. The question is whether dbo.GetId() is called only once for entire query and its result is then applied or is it called for each row? I think it is called for every row, but I don't know of any way how to prove it.

Also would following query be more efficient?

```
DECLARE @Id int
SET @Id = dbo.GetId()
SELECT * FROM {tablename} WHERE ColumnId = @Id
```

Comment: increment a specific value (an int value in table row) inside the function and you'll know.

Comment: The answer is yes and yes.

Comment: Because there is no way to know what output is expected in `dbo.GetId()` function so it executed the function per row.

Comment: @dotNET - that would be an impressive achievement since DML is banned inside functions.

Comment: What are your specific requirements here? Are you looking for a *guarantee* of some kind, and if so, what form? That it's called *at least* once, *at most* once, *exactly* once, per row?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: I just need to prove that it is called for each row in that table and thus the performance is decreased. In any way.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Thanks for the heads up. I recall I had learnt that somewhere in the past too.

Answer (score 3):

I doubt this is guaranteed anywhere. Use a variable if you want to ensure it.

I amended @Prdp's example

```
CREATE VIEW vw_rand
AS
  SELECT Rand() ran

GO

/*Return 0 or 1 with 50% probability*/
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Udf_non_deterministic ()
RETURNS INT
AS
  BEGIN
      RETURN
        (SELECT CAST(10000 * ran AS INT) % 2
         FROM   vw_rand)
  END

go

SELECT *
FROM master..spt_values
WHERE dbo.Udf_non_deterministic() = 1
```

In this case it is only evaluated once. Either all rows are returned or zero.

The reason for this is that the plan has a filter with a startup predicate.

[image]

The startup expression predicate is `[tempdb].[dbo].[Udf_non_deterministic]()=(1)`.

This is only evaluated once when the filter is opened to see whether to get rows from the subtree at all - not for each row passing through it.

But conversely the below returns a different number of rows each time indicating that it is evaluated per row. The comparison to the column prevents it being evaluated up front in the filter as with the previous example.

```
SELECT *
FROM master..spt_values
WHERE dbo.Udf_non_deterministic() = (number - number)
```

And this rewrite goes back to evaluating once (for me) but `CROSS APPLY` still gave multiple evaluations.

```
SELECT *
FROM master..spt_values
OUTER APPLY(SELECT  dbo.Udf_non_deterministic() ) AS C(X)
WHERE X = (number - number)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the info. :) I will keep my answer just for a reference in your answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to prove it

### View

View is created to add a `Nondeterministic` inbuilt Functions inside `user defined function`

```
CREATE VIEW vw_rand
AS
  SELECT Rand() ran
```

### Nondeterministic Functions

Now create a `Nondeterministic user defined Functions` using the above view

```
CREATE FUNCTION Udf_non_deterministic ()
RETURNS FLOAT
AS
  BEGIN
      RETURN
        (SELECT ran
         FROM   vw_rand)
  END
```

**Sample table**

```
CREATE TABLE #test
  (
     id   INT,
     name VARCHAR(50)
  )

INSERT #test
VALUES (1,'a'),
       (2,'b'),
       (3,'c'),
       (4,'d')

SELECT dbo.Udf_non_deterministic (), *
FROM   #test
```

**Result:**

```
id  name    non_deterministic_val
1   a       0.203123494465542
2   b       0.888439497446073
3   c       0.633749721616085
4   d       0.104620204364744
```

As you can see for all the rows the function is called

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does get called once per row.
See following thread for debugging functions
[SQL Functions - Logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721726/sql-functions-logging/10721985#10721985)

And yes the below query is efficient as the function is called only once.

```
DECLARE @Id int
SET @Id = dbo.GetId()
SELECT * FROM {tablename} WHERE ColumnId = @Id
```

Comment: `PRINT` within a function is a side-effecting operator so it doesn't allow you to have `PRINT` within a `FUNCTION`.